# Как передать значение из конкретного input range в конкретный div

Tags: javascript

```
let ranges = document.querySelectorAll('.range');
let results = document.querySelectorAll('.result_item');

ranges.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('input', () => {
    return el.value;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ranges.forEach((el, index)=>{
    return results[index].textContent = el.value
})
```

Не знаю правильно ли тебя понял...

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```js
const ranges = document.querySelectorAll('.range');

ranges.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('input', () => {
    el.closest('.parent').querySelector('.result_item').textContent = el.value;
  })
})
```

```css
.parent {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="range" class="range" name="r" value="0">
  <div class="result_item">0</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <input type="range" class="range" name="r" value="0">
  <div class="result_item">0</div>
</div>
```